Getting Http error 500 on a Blazor server app after a while that it receives no more request
I have a Blzor server application that works fine as a Windows service, but sometimes after a while that there are no web requests, I get http error 500 when opening a page. It seems that there is no listening engine on the port or that the requests were not honored and not forwarded to the application. In this case, when I restart the service, it works as expected.
Is there any way to detect this situation and solve this issue?
